# Error when building locally in Cordova after adding cordova-plugin-admobpro

Tags: cordova-plugins, phonegap-admob

I have upgraded my Cordova CLI development environment to the latest versions. But still obtaining this error so I can't build my project:

The command:

```
cordova build android
```

The error message:

```
Error: Project contains at least one plugin that requires a system library. This is not supported with ANT. Palease build using gradle.
```

Anybody knows a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova. You may need to download last android sdk version

Comment: Thanks @C.Miller, but the problem occurs for every plugin using Gradle for building work. Probably the reason be a wrong update in my environment. So I opted for using the following workaround: `cordova build android -- --gradle`. I suposse the best solution will be to recreate the environment from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

[cordova-admob plugin](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova) author here.

As seen from your comment, you have problems with gradle. Maybe recreating the environment from scratch could help. Other thing you can try is to add the plugin at https://github.com/appfeel/phonegap-admob

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/appfeel/phonegap-admob
```

This is a mirror from `cordova-admob` but just changing the dependency method (this uses ant which makes it compatible with Phonegap Build).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Miquel. The problem affects all plugins using Gradle in my proyect. I also think recreating my environtment would fix the problem. By now I keep on using `-- --gradle` command options. If I recreate my env in the future I'll write here the results.